# Password sanitization within stacktraces & errors

Tags: java, security, logging, error-handling, sanitization

We're currently running into an interesting problem regarding the sanitization of error logs being printed into our server logs. We have proper global error handling set up and have custom error messages that are sent back as responses from our OSGi java servlets.

We use dockerized containers as server instances that are autoscaled, so we're thinking about setting up a log aggregator and storing our exceptions within a DB in the cloud, that way we can also track metrics about our exceptions and pinpoint how we could improve our development process to reduce certain types of errors, etc.

I did a bit of research about how that should be done and I [found this](https://owasp.org/www-project-cheat-sheets/cheatsheets/Logging_Cheat_Sheet.html). The OWASP Logging sheet cheat. It mentions that passwords should never be logged among a few other things. That brings us to my question:

**How do I go about properly sanitizing my logs without using some janky text processing or manually covering up all the potential cases?**

Example stacktrace:

```
pkg.exceptions.CustomException: some registration error 
ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "x_username_org_id_key"
  Detail: Key (username, org_id)=(SOME EMAIL, 1) already exists. 
  Query: with A as (some query) insert into someTable (..values...) Parameters: [X, X, X, X, X, SOME_EMAIL, THE_PASSWORD]
  at somepkg.etc
```

This is a pretty common error with registration systems that happens due to username collisions. Sure there's ways that this specific case can be avoided by ensuring the username isn't taken before the insertion isn't attempted and handling that case separately, but that's just a single case among many others.

After looking around to find a solution there doesn't seem to be an obvious way to solve the problem and I'm wondering if everyone out there has simply implemented their own version of a log sanitizer? We could simply purge the stacktrace if some troublesome strings are present, but that's not the best solution. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you only store and pass around password hashes you won't need to sanitize the logs for passwords. In cases where a password must be preserved temporarily in code use `char[]`s rather than `String`s. This is a more secure approach in general and is considered a best practice. The standard library APIs all use character arrays for passwords.